# Cypher UNWIND query very slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using the following query to UNWIND a list of data and update a node and a relationship that already exist in Neo4j. This query is very slow for Neo4j to UNWIND. The node I am matching has a SHA-256 serial number. c0ce8bc000be2e3cc7343db3f006b65a77d7923bd2f56bec3c6c91e084b715a7

Unwinding 500 rows of data takes on average of 24 seconds.

EDIT: I should also note that prior to running this query, I know the node ID and the relationship ID I am trying to update. They are in the list of data.

```
 MATCH (e:Business {serial_number: '${settings.ownerID}'})
 WITH e
 UNWIND ${data} AS row
 MATCH (e)-[r:OWNS_ASSET]->(a:Asset {serial_number: row.tempSerial})
 SET a.serial_number = row.assetSerial, a.signature = row.assetSig, 
 r.serial_number = row.OWNSSerial, a.signature = row.OWNSSig
 RETURN e
```

Comment: It's not clear where the ${data} comes from in your example (and that may cause the slowness), but is LOAD CSV an alternative for you ? Also, I'm assuming that there is a unique constraint (or index) on Business(serial_number) and on Asset(serial_number) ?

Comment: Hi Tom, we have tried load CSV and have very poor results. It's also part of a platform where generating CSV files for our data is very inefficient. LOAD CSV is very slow. The data it's comes from a STRING that has be formatted to the syntax Neo4j desires. [{row1},{row2},{row3}...]

Comment: Can you share a PROFILE of the above query then ? If you have indexes/constraints on both serial_numbers the above should only take milliseconds for 500 rows.
Also, is there a reason for not starting with the UNWIND and just having one MATCH : MATCH (e:Business {serial_number: '${settings.ownerID}'})-[r:OWNS_ASSET]->(a:Asset {serial_number: row.tempSerial}) ?

Comment: No there isn't. It is just how the prior query was structured.

Comment: Removing the MATCH WITH increased the time to 34 seconds.

Comment: [{ownerID:'f2c1a04ceca8f2401acc8d525f22bf314b209552e2f4a28ea06601c3f1eb02e5',tempSerial:'3ca974120cb8f781e57e4860a3fd072c647a4d2c07ed7794c00d74b8b2bc8c38batch0pac0',assetSerial:'bc381ac51eb44feb8694fd8d00cb4067284dc1dc20c4a4f19ac18dd0311a1a0b',assetSig:'Data',relID:'42015',OWNSSerial:'89e692d21f95f66dcbfe853ecdef86ee0193c74636fdd11f35be75680ea4548c',OWNSSig:'Data'}]

Comment: On a 500 row commit, there would be 500 of those in a string is handled by UNWIND. I will double check on the status of the indexes tomorrow as I must get to sleep. Thanks

Comment: Sure. And a screenshot of what a PROFILE shows would be helpful too :-).

Comment: B.t.w. the fact that the time increased after removing the MATCH WITH is an indication for me that there is no index/constraint on Business(serial_number). You are probably doing a full node label scan for every row now. And I'm not putting any money on it (yet :-) but the same is probably true for Asset(serial_number)

Comment: A couple questions... 1. About how many :Assets does the :Business own? 2. Does an :Asset only have one owner? If not, what's about the average number of owners for an asset?

Comment: What about index?

Comment: Tom, you were right, there was no index. I guess after 16 hours straight I forgot. :( With the index added, an unwind of 500 rows takes: 753ms 

The program itself is actually processing 5,000 rows, it takes the 5,000 and spins up 10 child processes (node.js), which then each processes 500 so its actually 753ms for the 5,000, in 10 batches of 500.